# Nelson Not Adding Connections

Tags: iri-node, vps, nelson

I am attempting to setup `nelson` https://github.com/SemkoDev/nelson.cli

I cloned the the `iri` and compiled with `mvn`. I run it with

`java -jar iri-1.4.1.2.jar  -c iri.ini`

iri.ini:

`[IRI]
PORT = 14265
UDP_RECEIVER_PORT = 14600
TCP_RECEIVER_PORT = 15600
NEIGHBORS = <NEIGHBOR1> <NEIGHBOR2> <NEIGHBOR3>
IXI_DIR = ixi
HEADLESS = true
DEBUG = true
DB_PATH = mainnetdb
API_HOST = 0.0.0.0`

Then I run `nelson --gui`
It seems to be running fine but its been up for close to two hours and it still hasn't found / added any connections.

Does anyone know what the issue might be? Thanks.

nelson --gui:

`┌───────────────────────────────────────┐┌───────────────────────────┐────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│Nelson v.0.2.2 - Status                ││                           │Peers                                                               │
│                                       ││                           │                                                                    │
│Started on: Monday, December 18th      ││⢀⣤⣶⣶⣦⣄ ⢀⣤⣶⣶⣦⣄              │Count: 0 (Connected: 0)                                             │
│2017, 16:59:36.173                     ││⣿⠏⠁ ⠉⢿⣷⣿⠏⠁ ⠉⢿              │                                                                    │
│Online: 1 hour 35 minutes              ││⣿⡄32%⣼⣿⣿⡄84%⣼              │Connections:                                                        │
│Epoch: 7                               ││⠙⠿⣷⣶⡿⠟⠁⠙⠿⣷⣶⡿⠟              │do not worry, this may take a while...                              │
│Cycle: 94                              ││                           │                                                                    │
│Epoch Interval: 900s                   ││ epoch  cycle              │                                                                    │
│Cycle Interval: 60s                    ││                           │                                                                    │
│Port: 16600                            ││                           │                                                                    │
│API Port: 18600                        ││                           │                                                                    │
│IRI Port: 14265                        ││                           │                                                                    │
│TCP Port: 15600                        ││                           │                                                                    │
│UDP Port: 14600                        ││                           │                                                                    │
└───────────────────────────────────────┘└───────────────────────────┘────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│6:24:57 PM.721    16600::NODE  new cycle                                                                                                 │
│6:25:57 PM.991    16600::NODE  new cycle                                                                                                 │
│6:26:58 PM.262    16600::NODE  new cycle                                                                                                 │
│6:27:58 PM.510    16600::NODE  new cycle                                                                                                 │
│6:28:58 PM.751    16600::NODE  new cycle                                                                                                 │
│6:29:58 PM.975    16600::NODE  new cycle                                                                                                 │
│6:29:58 PM.985    16600::NODE  new epoch and new id: <ID>│
│ <ID>                                                                                                                             │
│6:29:58 PM.994    16600::HEART new personality a <ID> │
│<ID>                                                                                                                                 │
│6:30:59 PM.249    16600::NODE  new cycle                                                                                                 │
│6:31:59 PM.541    16600::NODE  new cycle                                                                                                 │
│6:32:59 PM.786    16600::NODE  new cycle                                                                                                 │
│6:34:00 PM.46    16600::NODE  new cycle                                                                                                  │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nelson need list of entry Nelson nodes.

After updating to version 0.2.2 running `nelson --gui --getNeighbors` will add these entry nodes automatically.

Alternatively, you can create a nelson config file with address of entry nodes, for instance: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SemkoDev/nelson.cli/master/ENTRYNODES